# Can a friend see what sites I visit if they have had physical access to the router?

Tags: privacy

I never thought about this before but I'm a private person.  I'm staying at a friends' place using her Rogers internet using her router. Now can she be remotely logging the sites I go on? Any way to tell?

Edit:  We are not sharing the same computer. Just the connection. The router has no machine connected to it.

Why the downvote?

Comment: Your friend can just look at the logs generated by the router.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend is clued up on networking absolutely they can see what you are browsing - in fact any Internet provider between you and the sites you are looking at can see this.

To answer your question (I might gloss over some technicalities, but I'm sure my answer is overall correct - I do this kind of thing for a living) -

There are 2 types of web connections commonly in use - secure and standard.

For standard websites (ie http://*) anyone can intercept or redirect the data stream (and a router is technically able to do this).   If they can see the stream they can ascertain the exact page you are going to - not just the site - in fact, chances are extremely high they can hijack any login details you have etc.

For secure websites (https) - assuming your PC and the site you are going to are not compromised - all they will see is the IP address of the site, and the amount of data being transferred.  It is often possible to infer from the IP address what the site is - particularly with larger sites.

An additional attack vector - as has been mentioned - is DNS.  DNS is the process used to convert a domain name into an IP address.   This traffic is almost always able to be read by a router - THIS IS TRUE REGARDLESS OF IF YOU ARE USING THE NAMESERVER ON THE ROUTER OR ANOTHER NAMESERVER like 8.8.8.8.      This means that even if you are visiting a secure site, it is possible to use the DNS to work out the name of the site visited.

A last possibility - it is possible that their ISP may keep logs of the IP addresses you visited and have them available.   This is less common then it used to be due to the huge cost of storing and processing logs - but if they are being billed per gig of bandwidth (or similar), they probably have these records.    The NSA almost certainly has this information.

Now the good news - Most of this needs to be set up beforehand.    If your friend has a standard router without a harddrive hanging off it, and without a whole lot of knowledge and intent to deceive - they will not have this information - and - assuming they can only use their router - will not be able to recover most of it later (maybe some DNS stuff in some cases).   Doing this kind of thing is not rocket science, but it is outside the ability of most computer users - unless they are network or system administrators.

There is no definitive way to tell if your friend is logging your requests - but if you can go to the IP address of the router your friend is using (typically the gateway set up in your IP settings), and you can ascertain they are running "standard" firmware which the router comes with - and that firmware is not (anything)-wrt or "Tomato" you are *probably* OK.

Answer (score 0):

This site explains how to do URL logging in the router: http://www.howtogeek.com/68886/how-to-configure-your-router-for-network-wide-url-logging/

So, yes, you can do that. That doesn't mean your friend is doing it though.

If you want to be safe, you can avoid it by making sure you use custom DNS server and not use the router as a DNS resolver. Pointing your preferred DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (Google's free DNS) should help you avoid any DNS spoofing happening.

If your friend is really creepy, they can still log all IP addresses you initiated connections to, and then at a later time reverse-DNS them to hostnames. To get around this you can use a secure connection to a private server. VPN can achieve this. SSH-tunneling can achieve this. This way, the router only sees you talking to one single IP (the server you are SSHing or VPNing to) and from that IP you go to everywhere else.

Comment: You don't necessarily need logging functionality in the router to achieve this. On my router, I've set up primary and secondary DNS to be my always on notebook under DHCP configuration in router settings and if a connecting user doesn't supply a static IP, all their DNS lookups are passed through my computer. I set it up using [Acrylic DNS Proxy](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) for faster DNS resolution but it can also log every DNS request made

Comment: Using a VPN might be the only viable solution.

Comment: It's still the router that knows of the connections. IP routing has to go through the router to get to anywhere on the internet. It is the gateway of every connected client.
The router can very well log on the router, or offload the logging to a notebook.
In your case you are just making your notebook a DNS server. If a client has a custom DNS server set to resolve hostnames, you will not catch them. But the router doing normal IP packet forwarding will still see the destination IPs. And it can be configured to route them through your notebook, of course.

Comment: That's right, which is why using a VPN is probably the only way to hide your Internet activity from prying eyes.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because changing the nameservers will not hide Internet activity (although I do grant you that it removes 1 very small attack vector)

Comment: I love learning but oh so technical. ☺

Comment: @davidgo - I did mention that he can still see your internet activity by seeing what IP addresses you connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Truth be told, if your friend has physical access to your machine, the router probably isn't the easiest vector for looking at your web history. It's certainly possible, and the other posters have outlined rather well some of those possible methods. However, carrying out a simple threat assessment, it's far easier for your, ahem, 'friend' to discern your web history by simply accessing your machine directly, either by physically accessing your machine, or using a physical keylogger, or if they are so inclined, using hardware like a pwnbox.

One might suggest that if you are concerned that your 'friend' is snooping on your web browsing habits, that you either get a new friend, or get new browsing habits ;)